# Mostrar texto en textarea de view edit.blade

Tags: html5, laravel-5

Tengo algunos campos para texto del tipo textarea y no logro que se visualicen los datos ingresados en dichos campos en la vista Edit.blade, luego de ingresados en la vista create.blade

Aqui dejo un de mis campos textarea en el codigo de la vista edit:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Notas">Observaciones</label>
                <textarea name="Notas" rows="4" cols="20" value="{{$compasivo->Notas}}" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Aqui dejo el campo correspondiente al de arriba de la vista create:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Notas">Observaciones</label>
                <textarea name="Notas" rows="4" cols="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Observaciones..."></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola los textarea no utilizan el value como los input, en el caso de un textarea hay que poner el valor en medio de la etiqueta de apertura del  y la del cierre  .

```
 <textarea name="Notas" rows="4" cols="20" class="form-control">{{$compasivo->Notas}}</textarea>
```

Resultado

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Notas">Observaciones</label>
            <textarea name="Notas" rows="4" cols="20" class="form-control">{{$compasivo->Notas}}</textarea>
        </div>
 </div>
```